# QComboBox : select on Key_space

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I work on a Qt application in an embedded system and I only have a remote on which the main key is Key_space.

So, I would like to have a QComboBox on which you can select an item when pushing the Key_space button.

How to do it ? Maybe I should inherit from QComboBox and redefine keyPressEvent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Qt doesn't already handle this (and I would think it did, but could be mistaken), then you'll need to do a bit more than just handle the key press event in the combo box.  When you are selecting an item for a combo box, another window has been shown with the list of items in it.  You would need to handle the key press event for that window, somehow.

To do that, I would suggest inheriting from [`QComboBox`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qcombobox.html), and install an [event filter](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the pop up that is shown (look at the [`showPopup()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qcombobox.html#showPopup), [`hidePopup()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qcombobox.html#hidePopup), and [`view()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qcombobox.html#view) functions).  Make a slot that connects to the [`highlighted`](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qcombobox.html#highlighted) signal, and keep track of which index is highlighted.  Then, when the popup window gets a space key event, hide the popup and set the current index to the last highlighted index.

Comment: Qt doesn't handle this with de Qt::Key_Space, but thanks to your answer it now works for me.